# Align stroke along path (oval shape)

Tags: adobe-illustrator, path, icon

I'm trying to create this eye icon with eye lashes in illustrator:
[image]

But I'm not sure how I can align the the lashes (which are little strokes) along the oval shape.  I've tried with the blend tool by replacing the spine but it comes out like this:

[image]

Any ideas how I can do this?

Answer (score 1):

1. create your blend
2. create curved path
3. select both, Object menu > Blend > Replace Spine
4. Blend options > Orientation: Align to path

[image]